# how to send key value pair as like that to the url using ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, xml, api

This is the data I am trying to send to a url. I dont know which format is this(key = value). How can i send as it is? Please help.

```
ssl_merchant_id = my_vid_id   
ssl_user_id = my_user_id 
ssl_pin = my_pin 
ssl_show_form = true 
ssl_amount = 1.00 
ssl_result_format = HTML
ssl_transaction_type = ccsale
```

Please don't say XML or JSON. Can I send this as it is? If not then tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: What you send and how you send it entirely depends on what your server will accept. Do you know what that is?

Comment: these are some credential to do online payment. so in their documentation, they said these values should be posted to their url.

Comment: left to the '=' is key and right are the values. I have to change the values. But i dont know how to send it

Comment: I know how to send JSON

Comment: So if you already know how to send JSON, what are you asking? It would be much better if you asked how to do what you need to achieve instead of giving us the rather unclear and odd question above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jquery .param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) or just pass the data as the `data` param to `.ajax`, eg (I've used text to generate the data, you would use your variables as normal):

```js
var data = {
 ssl_merchant_id : 'my_vid_id',
 ssl_user_id : 'my_user_id', 
 ssl_pin : 'my_pin',
 ssl_show_form : true, 
 ssl_amount : 1.00,
 ssl_result_format : 'HTML',
 ssl_transaction_type : 'ccsale'
};

var url = your_url + "?" + $.param(data)

$.ajax({
    url: your_url,
    data: data
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```